# How to save my stuff?

Tags: unreal-engine4

This is probably as dumb question, but I can't find a straightforward answer. I'm just starting out with Unreal. I'm trying to save my levels. They always save as a Umap file and I can't change the file type it saves as. I can't open this file type either.

I tried save as, save current yada yada. All Umap.

How should I be saving my levels?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that I could only open my files from the engine. not my file explorer. Solved :| –